# Python: Compare a list to a integer

Tags: python, hex

Ok, no i dont believe this is a repeat question of the other ones on here. Here is what i am trying to do (I am new to Python and self teaching so bear with me).

I have a set of data that is a length of 3. This set makes up a hex value i.e. 0,9,9f is really just the hex value 99f.

I want to take that data set and compare it to an integer that i have (2463). I know there is a decimal to hex converter but how do i combine the data set or split apart the integer value to be able to compare the two to make sure they are equal?

Comment: Why is it a list if it's really a hex value.

Comment: It's the way the device was setup. Not my doings :)

Comment: Just as a terminology tip, you said that you have "a **set** of data." In Python (and mathematics), a `set` has a specific meaning: an unordered, unique set of data elements. What you probably have is instead a `list`, which is ordered and not necessarily unique.

Comment: @voithos Thanks for the brain food. Duly noted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Where your list is 3 elements containing '99f' - the following returns 2463

```
int(''.join(your_list), 16)
```